# Check if num X is divisible by num Y

Tags: beginner, ruby, homework

I wrote some code for a course:

> Create a program that takes two numbers from the user then find out if the first is divisible by the second. If not divisible, let the user know what the remainder is.

Here is what I currently have. Is this right? If so, how could I improve it?

```
puts "Enter number one"
num1 = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "Enter number two"
num2 = gets.chomp.to_i

if num1 % num2 != 0
    p num1 % num2
else p "The numbers are divislbe."
end
```

Comment: In theory, you could use a loop to get the numbers, but for code this short, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Mast Why can't you divide 0?

Comment: @vnp Hmmm, yes, you can. The usual shortcut is when dividing zero by anything to just output 0, but that's an optimisation, not a bug. My bad.

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense, since it's just a wrapper around a modulo operator, but ok. It's valid.

Comment: You guys are right about it being confusing. Here is the wording for the question "
2. Create a program that takes two numbers from the user then find out if the first is divisible by the second. If not divisible, let the user know what the remainder is". I had to get clarification from the instructor. He meant if the remainder is 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Calculate the remainder once. Right now you calculate it to the comparison, and again if you need to output it.
- Use `.zero?` for readable, idiomatic code
- Fix your linebreaks and indentation (don't put code on the same line as `else`
- Consider what to do if the divisor is zero.
- Optionally, extract the bit of logic that gets a number into a method

This is a (intentionally overwrought) example:

```
def get_int(message)
  puts message
  gets.chomp.to_i
end

numerator = get_int("Enter numerator")
divisor = get_int("Enter divisor")

if divisor.zero?
  puts "Can't divide by zero"
  exit
end

remainder = numerator % divisor

if remainder.zero?
  puts "#{numerator} is divisble by #{divisor}"
else
  puts "#{numerator} is not divisble by #{divisor}. Remainder is #{remainder}"
end
```

Comment: Simple code but once cleaned up, it changes a lot of things! Good answer :).

Comment: Good stuff. I have just discovered the style guide and this example shows a lot of good uses! Great job.

Answer (score 4):

I would `Integer(gets)` (calling Kernel#Integer) to parse each line, because it raises ArgumentError if the line isn't an integer.  For contrast, `gets.to_i` (calling String#to_i) doesn't raise ArgumentError.  For example, `Integer("23:45")` and `Integer("hi")` raise errors, but `"23:45".to_i` returns 23, and "hi".to_i returns 0.  This doesn't matter if the user always enters an integer.

The user might send end-of-file (Control-D in some terminals), causing `gets` to return nil.  When this happens, Integer(nil) raises an error or nil.to_i returns 0.  If it raises an error, the user would see Ruby's error message.

The lines don't need to be `.chomp`ed, because both Kernel#Integer and String#to_i do trim `"\n"` and other whitespace from the beginning and end of the string.